# Quen's alternate "Puppet" mode doesn't seem to work

Tags: the-witcher-3

In order to activate Quen's "puppet" alternate attack one must HOLD the Q key. When I do it out of combat, the quen sign is prominent in front of Geralt and the camera zooms in a bit - same effect as when it works successfully.

In combat, maybe every one out of 20-30 times I try it it actually succeeds. Is there a trick to it, much like parrying in combat that I'm unaware of? I simply highlight an enemy, hold up the guard and hold Q.

What happens is the enemy becomes stunned but there is no extended "puppet" animation.

Yes, puppet is equipped in my skills & talents menu.

Is this because of enemy resistances or something? It wasn't made clear.

Comment: Puppet is Axii not Quen

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually used the correct sign, as greg said, puppet is Axii, then you have to remember it usually only works against humans, rarely versus monsters.

Considering you write something about holding up a guard, it seems you actually are using Quen though. Quens alternate is a shield in front of you, which blocks damage and heals you when hit.

Additionally, I've read several reports about Axii Puppet being bugged (reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/3e9vxc/cant_get_puppet_axii_alt_cast_to_work_on_pc/ ), so possibly you are affected by this, though I never had any problems using puppet myself.